# DB2ZOS dialect not working after upgrading spring boot version from 1.3.5 to 1.4.2

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

After upgrading spring boot version from 1.3.5 to 1.4.2 seems to be DB2ZOS dialect not working for pagination query in Spring JPA earlier itwas working.
I am using Spring JPA with DB2, when i use paging repository and queries for second page it throws error. This is the generated query.

```
select
        * 
    from
        ( select
            inner2_.*,
            rownumber() over(
        order by

        order of inner2_) as rownumber_ from
            ( select
                componentd0_.comp_data_field_st_msg_id as comp_dat1_0_,
                componentd0_.comp_data_file_id as comp_dat5_0_,
                componentd0_.comp_data_file_field_id as comp_dat6_0_,
                componentd0_.component_serial_no as componen2_0_,
                componentd0_.controller_short_name as controll3_0_,
                componentd0_.message as message4_0_ 
            from
                cs_comp_data_field_st_msg componentd0_ 
            left outer join
                cs_comp_data_file componentd1_ 
                    on componentd0_.comp_data_file_id=componentd1_.comp_data_file_id 
            where
                componentd1_.comp_data_file_id=? 
            order by
                componentd0_.comp_data_field_st_msg_id asc fetch first 50 rows only ) as inner2_ ) as inner1_ 
        where
            rownumber_ > 25 
        order by
            rownumber_
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   :  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-199, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=OF;??( [ DESC ASC NULLS RANGE CONCAT || / MICROSECONDS MICROSECOND, DRIVER=3.69.24
2016-12-26 13:41:42.886 ERROR [componentdatafiles,c50b4d59a68eb961,c50b4d59a68eb961,false] AK51602      20296 --- [io-8081-exec-75] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   :  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-516, SQLSTATE=26501, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=3.69.24
2016-12-26 13:41:42.887 ERROR [componentdatafiles,c50b4d59a68eb961,c50b4d59a68eb961,false] AK51602      20296 --- [io-8081-exec-75] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   :  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-514, SQLSTATE=26501, SQLERRMC=SQL_CURLH200C1, DRIVER=3.69.24
2016-12-26 13:41:42.918 DEBUG [componentdatafiles,c50b4d59a68eb961,c50b4d59a68eb961,false] AK51602      20296 --- [io-8081-exec-75] c.d.c.n.service.NonDeereXmlServiceImpl   :  Critical system error

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:261)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:491)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMeta
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect` class generating invalid query that why its failing.I have override the `getLimit` function in my dialect and its resolved.

Comment: So it isn't spring but hibernate.... Dialect is a class from hibernate.

Comment: Yes you are correct its org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect class. I have edited answer.

Comment: Aren't you simply using the wrong dialect? For Z/OS you either have to use `DB2400Dialect` or `DB2390Dialect` not the default `DBD2Dialect`.

Comment: I have tried with DB390Dialect & DB2400Dialect but it not supporting DB2ZOS database